# separate appendix file with cross-referencing

Tags: cross-referencing

I have a tex file with appendices. The publisher wants separate source files for the body of the document and the appendices. However, I have used many cross-referencing in the appendices that refer to equations and theorems in the document body.

Is there any way that I can provide a separate tex file for the appendices without replacing all cross-references by hard typed numbers?

Comment: Probably [xr](http://ctan.org/pkg/xr)?

Comment: You may also use the package [zref](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/zref) and load its `xr-module`, which has severalof nice features.